# Which version of kernel/lvm allows for lvreduce of mounted (live) logical disk?

Tags: lvm

I have seen an experimental linux box where

```
lvreduce -rL -10G /dev/main/repository
```

worked without unmounting (i.e. even on root,home dir etc), but it does not on my server install

- debian squeeze
- LVM version:     2.02.111(2) (2014-09-01)
- Library version: 1.02.90 (2014-09-01)
- Driver version:  4.27.0
- Linux kernel: 3.16.0-4-amd64
- filesystem: ext3

what it the version combination which allows it?

PS: I tried to browse release notes of lvm but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Versions you have should allow that.

I suspect the problem that you've done `lvextend` which extended the lvm volume but you have not extended your filesystem. So that there's a limited size filesystem lives on larger device now.

You should be able to resize your filesystem via `resize2fs /dev/main/repository` ( `resize4fs /dev/main/repository`, `xfsgrow /dev/main/repository` or something like that for other filesystems).

Comment: I am aware of the fact, that it can be done in two steps - resizind the fs first and than reducing the logical volume. But the question holds - can it be done on mounted drive. (I know it can, but under which versions).

Comment: As I said - your versions are definitely fine. It's been there for years and your system is relatively fresh.

Comment: I did not use lvextend, I am using lvreduce - it was mistake in the question, but I corrected that already. So it is mystery, because lvreduce just asks to unmount the disk giving no chance to go around it. I will update the question with the complete communication on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The command you issued will **not** reduce your LV, rather it will grow the LV by 10GB, concurrently expanding its filesystem.

Shrink/reduce a LV is a much more delicate operation, as you need to be absolutely sure that the filesystem inside the to-be-shrink volume does not overflow the new volume limit. For filesystems which do not support shrinking (eg: xfs), you can not resize the LV at all.

Anyway, what exact error/log do you have when executing your command?

**EDIT**

ok, you are really speaking about growing the LV. On-line filesystem resize is a long-time supported features in pretty much any kernels. Can you post the log of your command? Please also add the output of `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs`

Comment: Yes it is a mistake in the question, sorry. I made the correction. I also added information about filesystem used (ext3). Thanks.

Comment: It is asking whether it should umnount the system and when I say now it refuses to continue. If the exact workding is needed I can paste it here.